# Media reader. Failed to open file. (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, file, media, audio-recording

I'm trying to record short audio files in android, and after play them using file path. I'm followed this [code](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder.html).

But I'm face next problem on method **mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);**

> Failed to open file '/storage/emulated/0/pronouncing2017-11-07 18:20:19.800.3gp'. (No such file or directory)

and after:

```
11-07 18:20:27.356 11327-11344/com.apps.vmg.mynewdictionary E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
11-07 18:20:27.357 11327-11327/com.apps.vmg.mynewdictionary E/Add_Word_Activity: prepare() failed
```

Using file manager device , i found this file and compare actual path with **mFileName** and they are equal

I'm found what cause this error. I have method:

```
private File getOutputFile() {
    return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
            "/pronouncing" + 
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date())
            + ".3gp");
}
```

But this way , it's works :

```
private File getOutputFile() {
    return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
            "/pronouncing" + "word"
//            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date())
            + ".3gp");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo , now I'm sure that Media player can't read file which in name include date with format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS".

With format "yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss" all works fine